# Expression Engine Site Hacked

Tags: database, expressionengine

I've just been contacted by an old client who has gotten an email from Google saying the following..

Dear owner or webmaster of http://www.beyondthestreets.org.uk/,

We are writing to let you know that some pages from http://www.beyondthestreets.org.uk/ will be labeled as potentially compromised in our search results. This is because some of your pages contain content which may harm the quality and relevance of our search results. It appears that these pages were created or modified by a third party, who may have hacked all or part of your site. Many times, they will upload files or modify existing ones, which then show up as spam in our index.
The following are some example URLs which exhibit this behavior:
·         http://beyondthestreets.org.uk/aligmnment-digital-systems-principles-and-applications-11th-e-digital-systems/....

The rest isn't relevant. I've had a quick look and they haven't edited the template files but when I look at the source it looks like it has been.

Its running 1.6.7 so its quite dated. I haven't got a copy of the database. Any advice?

Comment: Next time, you'll start by creating a disaster recovery plan (including regular physical backup) to avoid such situations. With the education of the customer to be sure it's effective.

Comment: Since we're talking about security, lets throw social engineering into the bargain: How sure are you that the email is in fact from Google? Have you checked that the results are in fact *labeled as potentially compromised* in their search results? I'm not saying it isn't, still.

Comment: "they haven't edited the template files" - external template files? What about the database version of the templates?  What about the entries? There are differing URLs referenced on the page, so either they modified existing pages and changed the URL, or there are new external files in root that are being picked up.

Answer (score 1):

From the change log of EE, version [1.7.0](http://expressionengine.com/legacy_docs/changelog.html#v170):

> Fixed a security issue that in certain circumstances could result in arbitrary code execution.

Not saying that this is what happened but it might be.  If so then you can't trust anything in your set up.  Not the templates, not the database, not the system files.

It's possible that your site host has backups even if they don't advertise that service for their own disaster recovery purposes, so it might be worth a shot to contact them.

If you are not able to recover I think the only *really* safe course of action would be a fresh install of EE, latest 1.x (or 2.x if you expect to develop the site further). You'll then need to examine each template, weblog entry, member account, and comment before importing them.

If a fresh install and import is beyond what you are able to manage then you might want to do a little forensics to see if you can determine which files and database records have been modified.  You can start by looking at the modification dates on the files.  But these can be faked too.  So you might also consider, at least for the stock EE files of running a file diff between a fresh install and your current state.

Also on a go forward basis, do what Steve B says and have a disaster recovery plan.  For database back ups we use [AutoMySQLbackup](http://sourceforge.net/projects/automysqlbackup/) for files we use [rsnapshot](http://rsnapshot.org/) both triggered from Cron, but there are lots of choices out there for this sort of thing, including services provided by your host.